# Wrong working b tree index in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, b-tree

Recently, I have problem with b tree index on one column in table. I create index:

```
CREATE INDEX t_client_contact_email on t_client_contakt (email);
```

Everything is OK, but after a few days, searching using this index dosen't work correctly. Rebuild this index (DROP - CREATE) everytning is OK.

What can I do with this? I'm using Postgres 8.4.

Comment: No, any errors. But if I search for example string (mail) - _example@whatever.com_ and I have it in table, i don't get any queries. For example:
SELECT * FROM t_client_contact WHERE email = 'example@whatever.com' I didn't get any queries (but I have this email in table)

Comment: And no error messages in the logs also? Can you reproduce this issue? What is the exact list of actions that leads to the failures?

Comment: No, in log I don't have any errors just correctly executed statment. This error is reproduced a few days after I create index, but when I drop and create index again, everything is OK... for a couple of days.

Comment: Which exact version of pg are you running? Can you update to latest 8.4.x and try again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be getting bitten by an old bug, that was fixed very recently.

See this:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4-11.html

Specifically:

Fix btree index corruption from insertions concurrent with vacuuming (Tom Lane)

An index page split caused by an insertion could sometimes cause a concurrently-running VACUUM to miss removing index entries that it should remove. After the corresponding table rows are removed, the dangling index entries would cause errors (such as "could not read block N in file ...") or worse, silently wrong query results after unrelated rows are re-inserted at the now-free table locations. This bug has been present since release 8.2, but occurs so infrequently that it was not diagnosed until now. If you have reason to suspect that it has happened in your database, reindexing the affected index will fix things.